# How to access private data of google calendar in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-calendar-api

I have to fetch **private google calendar events** in my android application. I am able to fetch public google calendar events but getting problem to fetch private calendar events.

I have generated client ID and a client secret, activated the **Google Calendar API** in the Google API Console and Generated access token.

```
private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {

    try {
     GoogleSignInAccount account=completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        String authCode = account.getServerAuthCode();
        String emailId = account.getEmail();
        mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.id_token_fmt,authCode));

        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Email", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString("email",emailId);
        editor.apply();
```

if anybody knows how to integrate private data from google calendar, please leave your answer.